# Running Basic Flex Projects over HTTP?

Tags: http, flexbuilder, localhost

How do you configure Flex Builder to run basic flex projects over http (http://localhost/MyProject.html)?  I can't figure out how to use crossdomain.xml files when running locally via something like file:///Users/Me/Flex/MyProject...

Running this on a Mac with Safari/FireFox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be worthwhile if you mentioned what OS you are developing on: Windows, or Mac OSX?

In general, you'll be asking Flex Builder to deploy your build to a web-accessible location provided already by the IIS web server (if on Windows), or the Apache web server (if on OSX.)  Here's how:

- choose Properties on your Flex project
- select **Flex Build Path** in the left panel
- change the **Output folder** for your project.

On Windows, you'll typically choose an output folder such as C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz ... where *xyz* is the name for a folder you created to hold your project's output files. That will be accessible as http://localhost/xyz/YourFlexApp.html

On Mac OSX, a good output folder to use is /Users/yourusername/Sites/xyz ... where *yourusername* is your user name, and *xyz* is the name for a folder you created to hold your project's output files. That will be accessible as http://localhost/~yourusername/xyz/YourFlexApp.html

**Important:** Ensure your local web server is installed and enabled.

Additionally, you'll want to change your Run/Debug settings so that Flex Builder launches your project via http:// URL instead of via a file reference.  Here's how:

- choose Properties on your Flex project
- select **Run/Debug Settings** in the left panel
- select your application in the main list
- click the **Edit** button
- under **URL or path to launch**, uncheck **Use defaults**
- change the Debug, Profile, and Run URLs to point to your web-accessible location.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  I made an alias like this:  ln -s /Users/Lance/Documents/Flex\ Builder\ 3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/flex.  I that okay?  It works :)

Comment: You're welcome. I imagine such a link could work fine, but bear in mind you're exposing *all* of your Flex projects and source to anybody on your LAN :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Flash setting, actually. You need to make the folder you're trying to run Flash in allowed by Flash. Go to this website, which runs a special component of Flash. http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Add the local folder location inside the 'locations' piece and make them Allowed. It's not super-intuitive getting it to save your settings, but it shouldn't take more than one try.